# C++/CLI marshal_context native strings corrupted

Tags: string, memory, c++-cli, marshalling

The following is C++/CLI code gets compiled into a DLL, and is called by a C# application:

```cpp
void Foo(String^ strManaged) {
    marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
    FooUnmanaged(context->marshal_as<const char*>(strManaged));
}
```

`FooUnmanaged()` reads the `const char*`, runs some processing which takes about a second, and then reads the `const char*` again, for example:

```cpp
void FooUnmanaged(const char* str) {
    // 1
    Log(str);

    // Process things unrelated to 'str'
    // ...

    // 2
    Log(str);
}
```

On occasions, the contents of `str` changes between the first and the second read inside `FooUnmanaged()`, as if that memory had been reused for some other purposes. This happens regardless of the processing done in `FooUnmanaged()`, as long as it takes a noticeable amount of time (I guess, long enough that the GC has a chance to trigger).

This does not happen if `Foo` is written either this way

```cpp
void Foo(String^ strManaged) {
    marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
    FooUnmanaged(context->marshal_as<const char*>(strManaged));
    delete context; // addded
}
```

or that way

```cpp
void Foo(String^ strManaged) {
    marshal_context context; // created on the stack
    FooUnmanaged(context.marshal_as<const char*>(strManaged));
}
```

Is the original code incorrect? Why does it not correctly reserve the memory of the `const char*` for the lifetime of `context`? Or can the lifetime of `context` be shorter than I think it is (the scope of `Foo()`)?

Comment: Yes, that's a lifetime issue.  .NET uses an aggressive collector, it has no idea that the native code relies on the context.  The first snippet requires GC::KeepAlive(context); at the end.  The last snippet is how it was meant to be used, stack semantics emulates RAII, the auto-generated Dispose() call keeps it alive in similar fashion.  And avoids the temporary memory leak.  If FooUnmanaged() stores the passed pointer then you can't use marshal_context.

Comment: This supports @HansPassant's answer: "The lifetime of [local variables] can depend on the way the program was built. In debug builds, a local variable lasts for as long as the method is on the stack. In release builds, the JIT is able to look at the program structure to work out the last point within the execution that a variable can be used by the method and will discard it when it is no longer required." Source: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by @HansPassant:

> Yes, that's a lifetime issue. .NET uses an aggressive collector, it has no idea that the native code relies on the context. The first snippet requires `GC::KeepAlive(context);` at the end. The last snippet is how it was meant to be used, stack semantics emulates RAII, the auto-generated `Dispose()` call keeps it alive in similar fashion. And avoids the temporary memory leak. If `FooUnmanaged()` stores the passed pointer then you can't use `marshal_context`.

This is confirmed by [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net/):

> The lifetime of [local variables] can depend on the way the program was built. In debug builds, a local variable lasts for as long as the method is on the stack. In release builds, the JIT is able to look at the program structure to work out the last point within the execution that a variable can be used by the method and will discard it when it is no longer required.